# ElasticSearch to fuzzy search all fields, boost exact matches, and boost other various match conditions

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Given the following query, how do I rank each should clause higher than another one.

I'm trying to boost them in the order that they're listed.

```
{
    "size": 20,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match_phrase": {
                       "fullName": "Michael Douglas"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match_phrase_prefix": {
                       "fullName": "Michael Douglas"
                    }
                },
               {
                   "match": {
                      "lastName": "Michael Douglas"
                   }
               },
               {
                   "match": {
                      "firstName": "Michael Douglas"
                   }
               },
               {
                   "fuzzy_like_this": {
                       "like_text": "Michael Douglas"
                   }
               }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

How do I boost each clause within the should array? This is what I can't wrap my head around.

Comment: I edited with the query and rephrased the question to be more direct at the end. I tried to get sample data, but editing all the personal info out was hindering the usefulness of the sample fuzzy results that came back.

Example: I'm simply looking to make the second should, the exact match on fullName, rank higher than the fullName phrase prefix. If I can do that, I should be able to finish the rest off.

Comment: Why do you need to?  If you just do a regular query string query with "Michael Douglas", Elasticsearch defaults will rank an exact phrase match higher than a single field match and that higher than a fuzzy match.

Comment: An example would be making LastName result first every single time.

Comment: Kielni I have a question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24528933/elastic-search-fuzzy-match-with-exact-matches-showing-first?noredirect=1#comment37983571_24528933 where by default to me, exact matches do not come out on top when using fuzzy matching.

Answer (score 0):

If you have very specific boosting needs you can wrap each of your queries in `function_score` queries:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html

Or `custom_boost_factor` prior to Elasticsearch 1.0

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/query-dsl-custom-boost-factor-query.html